# Input array is longer than the columns in this table

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, exception

I have a `csv_log_reader`:

```
DataTable csvData = new DataTable();

try
{
    using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
    { 
        csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
        csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

        string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();

        foreach (string column in colFields)
        {
            DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
            datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
            csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
        }

        while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();

            // Making empty value as null.
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fieldData[i] == "")
                {
                    fieldData[i] = null;
                }
            }    

        csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
        }
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

return csvData;
```

For the first csv file, I have 9 headers. For the second csv file, I have 10 headers, but the 10th header is null. For the second file, there is an exception thrown:

> Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

I want the 10th header's value to be `null`. How do I do this only for the 10th header?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have a csv file with 9 headers but 10 items in any row? `csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);` will throw `ArgumentException` with `Additional information: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.` as the exception message iff this is the case.

Example input that would cause this:

```
HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4,HEADER5,HEADER6,HEADER7,HEADER8,HEADER9
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 // Processing this row with your code will throw an exception
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

One thing you can do is simply guard against this scenario if you can't guarantee your input will always be valid.

```
try {
  csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
  Console.Error.Write("Input: ");
  fieldData.ToList().ForEach(d => Console.Error.Write(d + ", "));
  Console.Error.WriteLine("Input error: the exception message: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: @user3074200 Do you need them to be in the same data set as the ones with 9 columns, or in a different dataset with 10 columns?